# Syntax error when running class from execute anonymous

Tags: apex, developer-console, compile-error, execute-anonymous

I am trying to run a class in execute anonymous window to test, but am encountering an odd error.

Here is a simplified version of the class:

```
public class AddEmailProduct1 {

     public static void AddEmailAndSchedule (Opportunity Op){

        OpportunityLineItem OLI = new OpportunityLineItem (); 
         OLI.OpportunityId=Op.id;
         OLI.PricebookEntryId=Op.Pricebook2Id;
         OLI.Quantity=1;
         OLI.dclk__DSM_ProdName__c='Email';
         OLI.dclk__LI_StartDate__c=System.now();
         OLI.dclk__LI_EndDate__c=System.now();

         Database.insert(OLI,false);

    }

}
```

Here is my Execute Anon window:

```
AddEmailProduct1.AddEmailAndSchedule(0063D000002Oe6k);
```

Here is the error:

> `Line: 1, Column: 41 expecting a right parentheses, found 'D000002Oe6k'`

How do I call this class from Execute Anon window ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap your string in single quote characters (`''`):

```
someMethod('0063D00...')
//         ^          ^ You need these single quote characters
```

You also need to look at the signature, it accepts an `Opportunity` instance, not `Id`. In your particular case, you just need to construct a record and pass it in:

```
AddEmailProduct1.AddEmailAndSchedule(new Opportunity(Id='006...'));
```

You could also overload or re-write your method to just accept an `Id`:

```
public static void foo(Opportunity record)
{
    foo(record.Id);
}
public static void foo(Id recordId)
{
    // do stuff
}
```